# An inequality regarding Poisson process

Tags: stochastic-processes

Let $N$ be a Poisson process with intensity $\lambda$, for $0<\sigma<\tau$, we have $$E[\sup_{\sigma\le t\le \tau}(N_t/t-\lambda)^2]\le 4\tau\lambda/\sigma^2$$

I think this is by Doob’s inequality for a martingale, but it works only for a positive martingale, and I don’t know how to handle the sign of $M_t=N_t/t-\lambda$

Comment: It's Doob inequality and it works for any sub-martingale.

Comment: @Todd Thanks! Treating |X_t| a submartingale fixes it. I always forget the submartingale case.

Comment: No need $|X_t|$, but rather $X_t^2$ (which is a sub-martingale whenever $X$ is a martingale).

Comment: Yeah I think that also works. I use the absolute value and employ the $L^p$ inequality for $p=2$.